# jenkins task plugin empty dropdown for task list

Tags: jenkins

I suddenly got this on a jenkins broken build that uses the jenkins task plugin (failure):

```
channel stopped
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.plugins.batch_task.BatchTaskInvoker$Config.invoke(BatchTaskInvoker.java:109)
    at hudson.plugins.batch_task.BatchTaskInvoker.perform(BatchTaskInvoker.java:207)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1074)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1840)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Build step 'Invoke batch tasks' marked build as failure
```

In the build page it says `Downstream Tasks
* Invalid entry: name of project » name of task`

When I go to configure the project where I would put Post-build Actions invoke build tasks it has an empty dropdown for the task selector.  If I type in the build name it says "actually there are no tasks"

How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the task plugin had somehow gotten mis-configured.  Or at least the old task list deleted.

To fix it, go to the top of the `jenkins project -> configure` and there is another section called "batch tasks" that had gotten unchecked somehow.  Check it, add some more scripts, then the task selector dropdown at the bottom will start working (again), failure message goes away.  Suspect user error or some kind of corruption from stopping a build midstream.